# Shall you vs Will you

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, modal-verbs

I learned "will you~?" but I have never heard about "shall you~?" I thought that "shall" has similar meanings as "will". Is it unnatural to use "shall you~?" instead of "will you~?"

Comment: *Shall you* would be natural if it's used correctly. Do you have sentence examples?

Comment: It's not wrong, but it's hardly *natural*.

Comment: For example, Shall you open the window?

Comment: @02l4 I can't speak for the Brits but Americans and Canucks universally phrase it *Will you open the window?* if it's about some future action or (with emphasis on the *you*) whose turn it is to open the window this time; *Are you about to...* or *...going to open the window?* if it's about the person's plans in the near future; or *Could you open the window* [*for me*]? if it's a request.

Comment: Shall is used to make a suggestion: Shall  we leave now? Shall I open  the window? Only use: Shall I and Shall we for suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

This is from Practical English Language, by Michael Swan. It focuses on British usage, although it's quite complete on its mentions to AmE too.

> Questions with shall I/we are used (in both British and American English) to ask for instructions or decisions, to offer services, and to make suggestions. In American English, this is rather formal. Will is not used in this way.
>
> *Shall I open a window?* (not *Will I open a window?*)
> *Shall I carry your bag?*
> *What time shall we come and see you?
> What on earth shall we do?
>
> Shall we go out for a meal? Let's go and see Lucy, shall we?*

The book is clear in general terms that shall has pretty much disappeared from normal people's lives. This is the only case in which it mentions a particular use of it that doesn't mean "will" in the whole book.
I am no native speaker, but I bet that all comments talking about differences in meaning are talking from their own perspectives of the language. That doesn't necessarily reflect what the word really means. There may be some regional or personal uses that differ. The only difference in meaning I know of is a classist one. So, the subjective description of the nuances in meaning between both words that a working-class native English speaker will give shall be different than the one of an Oxbridge student. Only certain people use the word instead of will nowadays, and that gives it connotations. Now, when do those "certain people" use shall and when do they use will would be an interesting case for study.

I've found another use:

After let’s . . . (in suggestions, etc.), we use "shall we?"
Let’s have a party, shall we?

Also, in same-way question tags:

I ’ll hold that for you, shall I?

New Zealand English tends to use Will I . . .? in questions like "Will I call back later?", where British English has Shall I . . .?

Answer (score 0):

The rule of thumb in spoken English is to **always use *will*** when talking about the future, although *shall*'s past tense and subjunctive mood *should* has taken on a separate life of its own.

On formal tests employing British English, you will sometimes encounter the old distinction (effectively dead in the spoken language) that you should use ***shall* for first-person pronouns and *will* for the rest**:

> I **shall**, and we **shall**.

but

> You/She/He/It/They **will**.

*Shall* implies a personal promise that this action certainly will occur in the future ("will have to...", "must...", "undertake to assure that..."), a promise which one cannot make for others. It works in the question *shall you?* since you're asking if the other person is assuming such an obligation... still, much too stilted for use outside Buckingham Palace. *You shall* or *shall not* implies divine commandment and threat of force to ensure that the action will come to pass. It's seldom seen outside of law and increasingly rarer there.

Comment: It's a trudge but, if you want the full story, [here](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/177350)'s the *OED* entry. The sense we're talking about and its usage note are in section 8. CTRL+F for "mere auxiliary"...

Comment: Important to note that if you fall into the water near a group of old-fashioned schoolmasters you should not shout "I will die and nobody shall save me" as that amounts to a suicide note.

Answer (score 0):

"Shall you...?" is a *challenge*, a *dare*, or a *demand* thinly disguised as a question.   For example,

- Shall you come?

You are obligated in some way to attend but it is unknown whether or not you will attend. If a specific time of arrival is required the question would become

- "When **shall** you come?"

Or perhaps the questioner simply wishes to impress upon you the seriousness of the event by making you specify a time of arrival. Either way, using *shall* instead of *will* indicates a NON-VOLUNTARY FUTURE ACTION.

Compare:
"You will come, won't you?" to "Shall you come?"
"will you" seems to plead while "shall you" seems hurled at your head aiming to hurt.

Comment: You could just as well say: "You shall come, shan't you?" It's just an outdated form, nothing in the least threatening.

Answer (score 0):

I would naturally say **will you**, but **shall you** and **will you** mean the same things, so either is acceptable. If you were writing using formal language, then **shall you** would most likely be the way to go. However, if you want to just write a normal sentence, I would write **will you**.

Answer (score 0):

*I will* is to show volition, deliver a promise; in simple future tense, one should say *I shall* to indicate that which he plans to achieve.  When it comes to interrogatives (for second persons), therefore, unless asking for a promise, we should say *shall you?* instead of *will you?*

Answer (score -1):

The meanings are similar, but **shall** implies an obligation (not strictly) while **will** implies a plan or expectation of future ocurrence regardless of obligation.  **Shall** is more commonly found in legal language and formal agreements that create obligations, or older text/more formal settings.

Comment: *Going to* can imply a plan; *will* just states the belief that the event is coming without any limitation at all. Also important to note the distinction between phrasing in the 1st and other grammatical persons.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to imply a plan; I didn't list all of them because that seemed out of scope for the question.  Edited to clarify expectation.

Comment: There are, quite. *Will* isn't one of them. There's nothing plannish implied by it at all, though it may be used in the description of one's plans.

Comment: -1 to that comment. I hear *will* used to learn about a person's plans **very** often.

Comment: Their plans are presumably included in their beliefs about the future. Semantically, you're still asking about the *latter* one and not the former.